# Allow anonymous only read in mosquitto

Tags: access-control-list

I'm trying to achieve a mosquitto broker with two listeners. One insecure and one TLS-secured. Basically so, that for subscription (reading) topics you don't have to provide any credentials and stuff. But it does not work. Anonymous users are still able to publish to topics.

I consulted the [man page](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) and IMHO did everything right, but as long as I have the line `allow_anonymous true` even with the first line in acl with `topic read #` it allows anonymous write. I double checked with `allow_anonymous false` using an user that's not included in the ACLs to verify. In this case I'm still able to publish to topics like `foo/generic/something` only thing that changed is, that a valid user is required, but ACLs still don't work as I would expect.

So basically even the man page states

> The first set of topics are applied to anonymous clients, assuming allow_anonymous is true.

It does not work. What am I doing wrong?
I'm using mosquitto 1.4.7. I appended my configs below (paths are a bit crazy, because I'm on a shared machine)

**mosquitto.conf**

```
retry_interval 30
sys_interval 15
store_clean_interval 15
pid_file /home/johndoe/mosquitto/pidfile.pid
port 61883

# tls listener
listener 61884
cafile /home/johndoe/mosquitto/tls/ca.crt
certfile /home/johndoe/mosquitto/tls/server.crt
keyfile /home/johndoe/mosquitto/tls/server.key
require_certificate false
tls_version tlsv1.2

# acls
acl_file /home/johndoe/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.acl
password_file /home/johndoe/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.passwd
allow_anonymous true
```

**mosquitto.acl**

```
topic   read    #

user    john
topic   readwrite       foo/
```

Comment: I also found this page (https://troy.dack.com.au/mosquitto-mqtt/) that gives an example of acls matching mine. I'm scratching my head :-(

Comment: Make sure to use spaces and not tabs to seperate the fields in the acl file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used tabs to separate the fields in the ACL file. The ACL file requires the use of (any number of) spaces.

While the man page does not explicitly state this the file is parsed by strtok_r with a delimiter of " ". Meaning only spaces are acceptable delimiters.

So to make your access control work simply replace the tabs by spaces.